# Горизонтальная рулетка

Tags: php, javascript

Всем привет, есть уже давно слитый код горизонтальной рулетки, вопрос в том как мне после нажатия кнопки сделать так чтобы её нельзя было нажимать повторно до окончания прокрутки рулетки.
И второй вопрос как мне переменную stopImageNumber передать в PHP да и еще без обновления страницы. Кому не лень спасибо за помощь

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 <style type="text/css">body{
   position:relative;
 }

 .roulette-inner img{
   width:72px;
   height:72px;
   margin:2px;
 }

 .roulette-inner img.active{
   border:2px solid rgba(89,0,153,.2);
   box-sizing:border-box;
   border-radius:50%;
   padding:-4px 4px 2px 4px;
   transform:scale(1.7);
   z-index:1000;
   background-color:rgba(0,255,127,.5);
 }
 </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
 jQuery.easing['easeOutCirc'] = function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  return c * Math.sqrt(1 - (t=t/d-1)*t) + b;
 }
$(function() {
    var option = {
        speed: 6,
        duration: 3,
        stopImageNumber: 4
    };

 $("#go").click(function() {
    option.stopImageNumber = Math.random() * 11|0;
    $(".roulette-inner  img").removeClass("active");
    $("#config").text(JSON.stringify(option));
    $({
        left: 0
    }).animate({
        left: 844 * option.speed + 75 * (option.stopImageNumber + 6)
    }, {
        duration: option.duration * 1000,
        easing: "easeOutCirc",
        step: function(a) {
            $(".roulette-inner").css("transform", "translateX(-" + a % 844 + "px)");
        },
        complete: function() {
            $(".roulette-inner  img").eq(option.stopImageNumber + (option.stopImageNumber < 6) * 11).addClass("active");
        }
    });
  })
});
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Config: <span id="config"></span></h2>
<div class="roulette" style="overflow: hidden; height: 126px; width: 844px;">
<div class="roulette-inner" style="position: relative; top: 24px; width: 7000px;">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/skryshtafovych/Lottery-html5/master/star.png" style="display: block; float: left;">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/skryshtafovych/Lottery-html5/master/flower.png" style="display: block; float: left;">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/skryshtafovych/Lottery-html5/master/coin.png" style="display: block; float: left;">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/skryshtafovych/Lottery-html5/master/mshroom.png" style="display: block; float: left;">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/skryshtafovych/Lottery-html5/master/chomp.png" style="display: block; float: left;">
<img src="https://icon-icons.com/icons2/206/PNG/128/Flower_-_Fire_24653.png" style="display: block; float: left;">
<img src="http://img.informer.com/icons_mac/png/128/218/218340.png" style="display: block; float: left;">
<img src="https://icon-icons.com/icons2/249/PNG/128/Lamp_27000.png" style="display: block; float: left;">
<img src="http://www.iconninja.com/files/817/63/651/orange-monster-icon.png" style="display: block; float: left;">
<img src="http://www.fsiv.com/public/images/logo-share/green/logo8.png" style="display: block; float: left;">
<img src="http://wiki.tockdom.com/w/images/3/36/Piranha_Plant_Cup.png" style="display: block; float: left;">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/skryshtafovych/Lottery-html5/master/star.png" style="display: block; float: left;">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/skryshtafovych/Lottery-html5/master/flower.png" style="display: block; float: left;">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/skryshtafovych/Lottery-html5/master/coin.png" style="display: block; float: left;">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/skryshtafovych/Lottery-html5/master/mshroom.png" style="display: block; float: left;">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/skryshtafovych/Lottery-html5/master/chomp.png" style="display: block; float: left;">
<img src="https://icon-icons.com/icons2/206/PNG/128/Flower_-_Fire_24653.png" style="display: block; float: left;">
<img src="http://img.informer.com/icons_mac/png/128/218/218340.png" style="display: block; float: left;">
<img src="https://icon-icons.com/icons2/249/PNG/128/Lamp_27000.png" style="display: block; float: left;">
<img src="http://www.iconninja.com/files/817/63/651/orange-monster-icon.png" style="display: block; float: left;">
<img src="http://www.fsiv.com/public/images/logo-share/green/logo8.png" style="display: block; float: left;">
<img src="http://wiki.tockdom.com/w/images/3/36/Piranha_Plant_Cup.png" style="display: block; float: left;">
</div>
</div>
<button id="go" onclick="play()">Go</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: для передачи без обновления страницы есть ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для отключения кнопки:

После

`$("#go").click(function() {`

вставь

```
$('#go').prop('disabled', true);
```

И после

```
$(".roulette-inner  img").eq(option.stopImageNumber + (option.stopImageNumber < 6) * 11).addClass("active");
```

Вставь

```
$('#go').prop('disabled', false);
```

Для отправки

```
$.getJSON("путь до скрипта php", {option: option.stopImageNumber},
  function(data){
    //data - полученный результат от скрипта
  }
);
```

В самом скрипте php, получаем результат от js

```
$option = $_GET['option']
```